# Broadcast from service when the device's screen is off

Tags: android

I have a service that acts as a countdown and upon completion it sends a broadcast.
The broadcast receiver is registered in the `onCreate()` method of the app's Application class.
The problem is that the broadcast doesn't get received until the device's screen is turned on. I know the Application doesn't get destroyed, I know the broadcast is sent on time, but for some reason it's not received until the user turns the screen on.

1. Why does this happen when the receiver is in the Application class?
2. How do I make it receive the broadcast even if the screen is off?

Comment: "I have a service that acts as a countdown and upon completion it sends a broadcast" -- please do not do that. [Only have a service running when it is actively delivering value to the user](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html). Watching a clock tick does not qualify. Use `AlarmManager` to get control at your desired time, so that you do not need a running service.

Comment: The service _is_ actively delivering value to the user while it's running. It's not just a countdown and is quite necessary - I just didn't feel explaining its intricacies would contribute useful information towards getting my question answered.